# Develop Android App On Bluej

Tags: android, bluej

We are using BlueJ to develop simple apps in my an intro class for students.

I would like to effectively develop a basic Android app in BlueJ.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueJ is an IDE.  So its just an editor.  That means it would be possible, combined with the Android SDK-  but practically it would probably be more painful than using Android Studio, where all the tools are built in.  Please note that there are significant differences between an Android app and a Java app in the UI and the lifecycle of the application.  So it isn't just taking a desktop app and compiling it for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Bluej is just an IDE.  It is generally used by beginners to write simple programs.  If you want to develop Android apps I would suggest you to use Android studio as all the functions and tools are pre-built in the application.  You just need to have basic Java knowledge and XML understanding to write the code.  If you want to to develop an application without any coding knowledge then I would suggest you to use thunkables or MIT App inventor.  Using any of these you just need to develop your own logic and create an awesome app without coding.